# How to do a GET request with params with dates ranges

Tags: java, testing, request, get, karate

im using karate framework to test some site, but one call to the endpoints is like this: `https://urlbase/index?id=60&filters[start_date]=Fri%20Nov%2018%202022%2010:14:59%20GMT-0300&filters[end_date]=Sat%20Nov%2019%202022%2023:59:59%20GMT-0300`

And i have problems with the filters[...] i don't know how to do that :(

I have this query def:

```
 * def query = {id: 60, filters[start_date]:'Fri%20Nov%2018%202022%2010:14:59%20GMT-0300', filters[end_date]:'Sat%20Nov%2019%202022%2023:59:59%20GMT-0300'}
```

But the request url shows: GET https://urlbase/index?id=60&filters=%7Bstart_date%3D%2C+end_date%3D%7D
`
with no brackets.

And i want my GET url looks like this: `https://urlbase/index?id=60&filters[start_date]=Fri%20Nov%2018%202022%2010:14:59%20GMT-0300&filters[end_date]=Sat%20Nov%2019%202022%2023:59:59%20GMT-0300`

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it seems to work fine:

```
* url 'https://httpbin.org/anything'
* param id = 60
* param filters[start_date] = 'Fri Nov 18 2022 10:14:59 GMT-0300'
* param filters[end_date] = 'Sat Nov 19 2022 23:59:59 GMT-0300'
* method get
```

You can look at the response and confirm the server handles the request correctly:

```
{
  "args": {
    "filters[end_date]": "Sat Nov 19 2022 23:59:59 GMT-0300", 
    "filters[start_date]": "Fri Nov 18 2022 10:14:59 GMT-0300", 
    "id": "60"
  }, 
  "data": "", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/17.0.4.1)", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-6377b983-6bfc4696374f7d08239de823"
  }, 
  "json": null, 
  "method": "GET", 
  "origin": "X.X.X.X", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/anything?filters[start_date]=Fri+Nov+18+2022+10%3A14%3A59+GMT-0300&filters[end_date]=Sat+Nov+19+2022+23%3A59%3A59+GMT-0300&id=60"
}
```